# Specifying certain characters for powershell script to run on

Tags: text, replace, parameters, find, powershell-2.0

This may be a complete shot in the dark, I have done some research and can't seem to find anything on this. But anythings possible with powershell I guess!

I asked a question earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472875/powershell-script-for-going-into-texts-files-within-a-directory-and-replacing-ch/)! on how to change certain characters in a script.

```
$infopath = Get-ChilItem "C:\Users\X\Desktop\Info\*.txt" -Recurse

$infopath | %{ 
(gc $_) -replace "bs", "\" -replace "fs", "/" -replace "co", ":" -replace ".name", "" | Set-Content $_.fullname
```

However there are some parts of the text file, that may contain bs, fs or co, that I don't want changing. Therefore what I would like to do, is add some sort of parameter into this existing script that only changes the text in the last 70 characters, or after the 4th # or after the 78th character.

Like I said, this could well be a ridiculous idea, but I would like to see other peoples views.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have found this `(78,$_.length-78-0)` which should only work with the text after the 78th character. However I cannot work out how to implement this into the existing code.

Comment: $infopath | %{ 
  $content = (gc $_); $content.Substring(0,78)+($content.Substring(78,$content.Length-78) -replace "bs", "\" -replace "fs", "/" -replace "co", ":" -replace ".name", "")|Set-Content $_.fullname
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your suggestion of getting the substring after the 78th character, I've created the following using 78 as the starting point. This leaves the first 78 characters unedited, and replaces the given strings after the 78th character. The whole file is replaced with the output.

```
$infopath = Get-ChilItem "C:\Users\X\Desktop\Info\*.txt" -Recurse
$startpos = 78

$infopath | %{
  $content = (gc $_);
  $content.Substring(0,$startpos)+($content.Substring($startpos,$content.Length-$startpos) -replace "bs", "\" -replace "fs", "/" -replace "co", ":" -replace ".name", "")|Set-Content $_.fullname
}
```

I hope this helps.

Thanks, Chris.